# How to auto store live streaming in server in php

Tags: php, web, webrtc, live-streaming, rtcmulticonnection

I am created a video streaming web application using RTCMULTICONNECTION, need to store every stream in my server.

When I click on the stream record button, the stream will be recorded, if it is a small length of video it will be uploaded into my server then it is a large length of the video it will through an error while uploading to my server.

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["video"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    $mime = $_FILES['video']['type'];
    if(strstr($mime, "video/mp4")){
        $path = $arr['url']."exampleurl/videorecording/".$filename;
        echo "success";
        // $filepath = '<video width="320" height="240" controls autoplay><source src="'.$path.'" type="'.$mime.'"></video>';
    } 
} else {
    // $path=""; 
    echo "fail";
}
```

how can I store video every 2/3 minutes into my server